# Could you help me : If (An) is a nested descreasing sequence of non-empty closed sets in the metric space M

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

If {A_n} is a nested decreasing sequence of non-empty closed sets in the metric space M.

**i)** If M is complete and $diam(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, how can I show that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is exactly one point.

**ii)** To what assertions do the sets $[n, \infty)$ provide counterexamples?

For the first part of the question, since $A_n$ is closed in M and M is complete, can I follow the way that infinite intersection of closed sets is closed and by definition of completeness any subsequence of $A_n$ will also be a convergent cauchy sequence so intersection of infinite n provide the limit (and a singleton) of sequences. Do you think this way is correct ? I do not have any idea about second part and need help.

Comment: $[n,\infty)$ doesn't provide a counterexample because the diameter is infinite for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof doesn't really make sense. You should argue existence and uniqueness of a point in $\bigcap_nA_n$ separately:

- For existence, prove any sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\in A_n$ for all $n$ is Cauchy, and explain why the limit must lie in $\bigcap_nA_n$.
- For uniqueness, use the fact that if $x,y\in\bigcap_nA_n\subset A_k$ then $d(x,y)\le\operatorname{diam}(A_k)$.

Comment: thank you for your help, so, for the existence, is the definition of completeness enough to show it? (since every cauchy must converge in M)

Comment: Yes, the argument I provided implicitly uses completeness.